# Add autoFill capabilities to jQuery-UI 1.8.1

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, autofill

here's what I currently have, unfortunately I cannot seem to figure out how to get `autoFill` to work with jQuery-UI... It used to work with the straight up Autocomplete.js

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    var thesource = "RegionsAutoComplete.axd?PID=3"
    $(function () {
        function log(message) {
            $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
            $("#log").attr("scrollTop", 0);
        }

        $.expr[':'].textEquals = function (a, i, m) {
            return $(a).text().match("^" + m[3] + "$");
        };

        $("#regions").autocomplete({
            source: thesource,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                //if the value of the textbox does not match a suggestion, clear its value
                if ($(".ui-autocomplete li:textEquals('" + $(this).val() + "')").size() == 0) {
                    $(this).val('');
                }
                else {
                    //THIS IS CURRENTLY NOT "LOGGING" THE "UI" DATA
                    //IF THE USER DOES NOT EXPLICITLY SELECT
                    //THE SUGGESTED TEXT
                    //PLEASE HELP!!!
                    log(ui.item ? ("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                }
            }
        }).live('keydown', function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            //if TAB or RETURN is pressed and the text in the textbox does not match a suggestion, set the value of the textbox to the text of the first suggestion
            if ((keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13) && ($(".ui-autocomplete li:textEquals('" + $(this).val() + "')").size() == 0)) {
                $(this).val($(".ui-autocomplete li:visible:first").text());
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

My JSON in the back end looks like this

```
[
    { "label": "Canada", "value": "Canada", "id": "1" },
    { "label": "United States", "value": "United States", "id": "2" },
]
```

I've used the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587378/how-to-implement-mustmatch-and-selectfirst-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete) to get the mustMatch working, but unfortunately if I "tab" away from the input box or if I type the word completely rather than actually selecting the suggested text, I get the "Nothing selected" response instead of an Value and ID.

Does anyone know how to extract the id out of the autocomplete when you don't actually select the field?

---

Basically, What I'm looking for is something similar to the `Month (local):` example found HERE: http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

But obviously using the **jQuery-UI** instead of the **jquery.autocomplete.js**

Comment: **IMHO** the guy from **bassistance.de** have done a good job, why you want reinvent the well!? you do better if you use you **jQuery UI** but deselecting the Autocomple component and using the one from bassistance.de - jQuery UI Autocomplete **7.45 KB** minified - jQuery plugin: Autocomplete **13.7 KB**
   minified

Comment: It's a good point but the one from bassistance.de is not in any CDN that I can find.  They say the one at dev.jquery.com is going to be taken down in favor of the jQuery-UI

Comment: Side note: try to avoid trailing comas in JavaScript objects and arrays. Some browsers do not handle them properly.

Comment: I've updated the jQuery-UI combobox demo to support autoFill. See my answer in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587378/how-to-implement-mustmatch-and-selectfirst-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete/6387781#6387781

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AutoFill has been deprecated in the JQuery UI version of autocomplete, and the jquery.autocomplete plugin is no longer supported.

[Here is a link to a github solutiuon.](http://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js) This will automatically select the first item in the list if you tab out of the field, and have "selectFirst: true" set as an option on your autocomplete call.

```
(function( $ ) {

$( ".ui-autocomplete-input" ).live( "autocompleteopen", function() {
    var autocomplete = $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ),
        menu = autocomplete.menu;

    if ( !autocomplete.options.selectFirst ) {
        return;
    }

    menu.activate( $.Event({ type: "mouseenter" }), menu.element.children().first() );
});

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: What the best way to call this extension?  I modified the code so it runs on document ready, and it works, but I think I'm missing something - is there an easier way? (I'm still pretty new to jquery/js)

Comment: It's not immediately obvious, I agree, but basically what happens is when you call the autoComplete method, JQuery adds a css-class called ".ui-autocomplete-input" to the textbox. This function automatically attaches to that class and monitors its events to select the item. You shouldn't actually need to do anything other than adding the code to your header after the autocomplete initialization.

Comment: Notice that it checks if autocomplete.options.selectFirst is set, otherwise it will just return. You neet to add selectFirst: true, to the config object, or remove the if block

Answer (score 1):

<del>**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/akile3</del>

**UPDATED 2:** with TAB support! ;)

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/akile3/8

try something like this:

not sure if is what you want, anyway it autofill entire word if match something!

```
$(function() {
 var json_source = [
        { "label": "Canada", "value": "Canada", "id": "1" },
        { "label": "United States", "value": "United States", "id": "2" }];

    $('<span id="hold"></span>').insertAfter('#regions');
    var $text_was = $('#hold');
    var $log = $('#log');

    $("#regions").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: json_source,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            var first_option = $('.ui-autocomplete li:eq(0) a').text();
            $(this).text(first_option);
            $text_was.text(first_option);
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
          var prev_text = $text_was.text() ? $text_was.text() : json_source[0].value ;
            $log.empty();
            var message = (prev_text != this.value) ? 
            'Nothing selected, input was ' + prev_text : 
            'Selected: ' + ui.item.value + ' aka ' + ui.item.id;
            if (prev_text != this.value) 
              $(this).val( prev_text  );

            $log.append(message);
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $text_was.text(ui.item.value);
            $(this).blur();
        }
    }).blur(function(){
      if( this.value == '' )
     $(this).autocomplete('search', json_source[0].value );
    return false;
  });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  I tried it on jsbin, but the problem is that when I use "TAB" to navigate away from the field, I do not get the appropriate data from the AutoSuggest.  I need it to autofill for me.

Comment: I realize that this works, however the above code doesn't get the ID unless it's actually clicked.  IE: the `aka: #`

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - not quite, assuming you extract you json array outside the Autocomplete plugin, then, you can access the id by using ex.: `json_source[0].id` look at this other example http://jsbin.com/akile3/10 **Note:** the example is designed to alert if you left all field blank and use TAB.

Answer (score -2):

If you simply want to autofill this is the code I am using.

```
$("#regions").autocomplete({
        source: thesource
    }).live('keydown', function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        //if TAB or RETURN is pressed set the value of the textbox to the text of the first suggestion
        if ((keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13) && $(".ui-autocomplete").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).val($(".ui-autocomplete li:visible:first").text());
        }
    });
```