# Automated clicked input type in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I'm having trouble and confused, is there any trigger event in Jquery to click automatically the input type using the `id` of the input type? The thing is I have a problem in terms of loading all data from my input type, it's just like `typeahead or autocomplete`, and I don't want to click the input type manually. it will very helpful for me.

*Before click*

[image]

After clicked

[image]

```
<input class="form-control" id="kt_typeahead_1" type="text" placeholder="States of USA"  v-model="formFields.fullname"/>
```

*Script*

```
 mounted() {
    this.autoComplete();
},

autoComplete() {

   $("#kt_typeahead_1").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: ```$("#kt_typeahead_1").trigger('click');``` Doesn't this do the job for you?

Answer (score 0):

`$('input#kt_typeahead_1').autocomplete("search");` will initiate the autocomplete search.

If you wanted to put a value in there first so it has something to search for, `$('input#kt_typeahead_1').val("My value")` - *and then the autocomplete.search method above*

If you just want to give the input a focus, `$("#kt_typeahead_1").focus()`

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work. I just wanted to click again automatically the input type to trigger again it is possible?. The thing is I've been fetching data through API

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand. Walk me through it. the page loads, then...

Comment: I appreciate your response, sorry. The problem is,  the image above that indicates `before click` when I've typed something, it will trigger the result but it will only pop up the result when you click again the input type, the image is just like above after click

Comment: and now I've been finding a way to click automatically the input type it is possible?

Comment: are you saying that as you're typing something, you want the closest match to pre-fill the input area? It will still show the pull down menu, but will also prefill the text box you're typing into with the closest match? Like google does in the search bar?

Comment: Yes exactly, currently it works now but you just need to click again the input type to show all pull down menu, and I've been thinking is there any way to trigger, click input type automatically.

Comment: This looks like a solution maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8137936/1772933