# JQuery UI AutoComplete functionaility doesnt have matching or autofill

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the latest autocomplete widget that is part of the latest Jquery UI. Two things that I need are autoFill to fill the textbox as I type and a way to match the values typed in with values in the DB. Does anyone know how to do this with the existing autocomplete? Thanks

Comment: if you want AutoFill to your autocomplete, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933713/add-autofill-capabilities-to-jquery-ui-1-8-1

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689405/making-jquery-uis-autocomplete-widget-actually-autocomplete ?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt make myself clear. I have a working autocomplete widget using jquery UI and returning JSON formatted data from a MVC 3 controller. Everything is working. What I want to add is the ability to complete the word as its being typed (autofill) and disallow values that doent exists in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: This will only work in modern browsers with support for [`input.setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.setSelectionRange). If you want a solution for older browsers, you're going to need to find a cross-browser solution.

Anyway, here's how I would approach this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            /* autofill: */

            /* If using AJAX, place your AJAX request here */
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(src, request.term)
                , el = this.element[0];

            if (results.length) {
                el.value = results[0];

                /* This will not work < IE9 */
                el.setSelectionRange(request.term.length, el.value.length);
            }

            response(results);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            /* mustmatch: */
            if (!ui.item) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SgxyT/

As you can see, `mustmatch` is *much* easier to implement. All you have to do is revert the value entered if it was not selected in the dropdown.

On the other hand, `autofill` will require you to use a function as the `source` for the autocomplete, determine the results, and set the selection in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You must write a server-side script, that builds proper SQL query and return matched rows in JSON format, compatible with autocomplete specification.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this link http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp ?

You can mention a server page as your data source. It is internally using the jquery ajax.

```
  $("#txtSearchKey").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "getcityname.aspx?term=" + $("#txtSearchKey").val(),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.CityName, value: item.CityId }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                }
    });
```

You should have a server page (in this example, getcityname.aspx) which reads the querystring value and make a call to your database to get the city names starts with what you entered in the text box with id "txtSearchKey". You can return the response by a response.write.