# How to implement jQuery UI Autocomplete 'autoFill' and/or 'selectFirst' features?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

First, Let me start by saying thatI am aware of other similar questions, like this one here:

[How to implement "mustMatch" and "selectFirst" in jQuery UI Autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587378/how-to-implement-mustmatch-and-selectfirst-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

but it doesnt really do what I would expect. I'll explain why below.
I am also aware of this simple guide posted by the original developer of the plugin:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide

and I have done many implementations of the former plugin and a few fairly customized implementations of the UI plugin.

Having said that, here is my issue and why the first solution does not work for me.
The soruce comes from a DB in the form of JSON objects. I use a custom function to set the options, see below:

```
source: function (request, response) {
   var sourceData = $.parseJSON(result); //result is an array coming in via ajax
   response($.map(sourceData, function (item) {
      return { label: item.PortName, value: item.PortName, source: item };
      //item has about 12 properties that could be used for other forms.
   }))
}
```

Then I also have a custom `change()` event that grabs the `source` above, and does a few things like store the item itself in the `data()` object of the element, as well as parse some of the data from the `item` object to be used in other form fields, etc.

The solution above only sets the value of the input to the first autocomplete option, but it does not replicate the `select` or `change` event of the autocomplete. So in reality is not a true `selectFirst` or `autoFill` replica.

The `change` function looks like this:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $('input:[name="another_form_field"]').val(ui.item.source.PortId);
            }
            else {
                $(this).val('');
                $('input:[name="release_port_id"]').val('');
            }
        }
```

which is a quick, simple, implementation of the mustMatch feature for now. This will most likely change once I have these 2 features implemented.

Ok, with all that said, any suggestions on how to implement either or both of these features? I have tried attaching a `blur` event as suggested in the question above, but that wont work.

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
This is what I have tried so far. Binding a `blur` event to the autocomplete element. The commented-out line uses the value of the first element in the dropdown and sets the text of the input. This would work if thats all I would need, but i need to replicate the select event, which means that i need more data (not just the text).

```
.live('blur', function (e) {
        if ($('.ui-autocomplete li').length > 0) {            
            //$(this).val($(".ui-autocomplete li:visible:first").text());
            $(".ui-autocomplete li:visible:first").click();
        }
        else {
            $(this).val('');
            $('input:[name="release_port_id"]').val('');
        }
    });
```

The other problem with this solution, is that it actually overrides the `change` event in the autocomplete and it does not execute as expected. Which is why I included the `else` section. This is not quite what it will look like, but a proof of concept.

Comment: I've updated the jQuery-UI combobox demo to support autoFill. See my answer in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587378/how-to-implement-mustmatch-and-selectfirst-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete/6387781#6387781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to post a bounty but finally figured it out.

Here is the solution I came up with. After playing around with this, I figured out that the plugin uses `.data()` to store the option item data. So I was able to get the full object and parse out the data that I needed to fulfill other elements. Then the challenge was to recognize when a selection was valid even if the user didnt click or select an option. For that I check to see if any options match the value, if they do I replicate the `select`. Otherwise I clear the fields. Then I leveraged the `.data()` again to store whether the choice was valid or not, and if it was not I was able to clear the fields again. Below is my code.

Comments are welcome.

```
$('#autocomplete_input').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.get("/DataHandler.ashx", { Type: "ExpectedType", Query: request.term }, function (result) {
                var sourceData = $.parseJSON(result);
                response($.map(sourceData, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.PortName, value: item.PortName, source: item };
                }))
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $('#another_element"]').val(ui.item.source.PortId);
            }
            else {
                if (!$(this).data('valid')) {
                    $(this).val('');
                    $('#another_element').val('');                    
                }
            }
            $(this).data('valid', false);
        }
    }).live('blur', function (e) {
        if ($('.ui-autocomplete li:visible').length > 0) {
            item = $($(".ui-autocomplete li:visible:first").data()).attr('item.autocomplete');
            $(this).val(item.label);
            $('#another_element').val(item.source.PortId);
            $(this).data('valid', true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nice Work :-) But Don't work with IE 8/9 This line fail : `item = $($(".ui-autocomplete li:visible:first").data()).attr('item.autocomplete');` The focus stay empty !