# How to make jqueryui autocomplete actually autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

You would expect AutoComplete to "complete" the phrase you are typing, but instead it "suggests" based on the characters you are typing.

For example:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

When you type "a" in the input box:

I expect it to "complete" and display: ActionScript AppleScript

Actually, it "suggests" and displays any word that contains that letter.

Here's an example on how you would expect it to work:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_basic_array.html

How would you get jQueryUI autocomplete to work like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate that has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382497/jquery-autocomplete-plug-in-search-configuration

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I believe the OP is asking about selectFirst or autoFill options to prefill the input with the first option available, hence 'autocompleting' the query, not just suggesting.

Comment: I've updated the jQuery-UI combobox demo to support autoFill. See my answer in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587378/how-to-implement-mustmatch-and-selectfirst-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete/6387781#6387781

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the (deprecated, but still usefull) [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) which does support what you want using the `autoFill` option