# Why did jquery ui autocomplete drop support for these feautures?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

the jquery UI team has a [blog on how to replace the legacy autocomplete and justifies that it can replicate all of the old features and options](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/08/extensible-autocomplete/).  Based on my testing, i dont think they can replicate:

1. **selectFirst** *if you have a remote data source*
2. **selectFirst** or **mustMatch** if you are using **multiple: true**

i see [this questions on how to replicate some of the legacy autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587378/how-to-implement-mustmatch-and-selectfirst-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete) options from [this plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), and there is a selected answer but it doesn't address these situations.

The jquery ui [folks have an example of replicating **selectFirst** in the new autocomplete](http://dev.nemikor.com/jquery-ui-extensions/autocomplete/selectFirst.html), but unless i am mistaken, it only works with local data source (not remote data source as the menu is usally not filled out before the event get called).

am i missing something or are these scenarios simply not supported in jquery ui autocomplete ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These scenarios are supported actually, but you have to extend ui.autocomplete widget to achieve desired behavior. Quick example to implement selectFirst feature:

```
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete2", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var self = this;
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            self._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
        // setTimeout is needed because jQueryUI automaticaly removes
        // active item just after menu rendering
        setTimeout( function(){
            self.menu.activate(
                // fake event object. Needed to avoid jQueryUI error 
                // (unsafe property access)
                {'type':'fake'}, 
                ul.find(':first') );
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

**Attention**: Always check if new widget is still compatible with new version jQuery UI!

**Update:** sample mustMatch implementation han be found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Comment: @dziastinux - why would they make you write these features yourself?

Comment: @ooo - I have no idea. I'll try to reopen feature request.

Comment: My guess is that they decided they weren't high enough priority to reimplement in the new code base, or that they weren't important enough to justify extra code complexity they'd add. But it's a shame, yes.

Comment: @dziastinux - thanks for the updated for selectFirst.  Any thoughts on mustmatch ??

Comment: @ooo I'm afraid mustmatch is a little bit more complicated. You see jQuery autocomplete was designed with non-mustmatch in mind. Plus there are questions about behavior: Do you want to allow typing? If yes, than what to do next when user types a value, you do not provide? Denying writing cant fit here as user might think field is broken... So the best way is to add error styling plus an error event (to display message). And that's just a start...

Comment: @dziastinux - I understand these decisions but why not just have the same behavior as the old plugin.  Again, they can't say this is an upgrade and simply not support existing functions.

Comment: I am sorry, there is example of mustMatch: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

Comment: @dziastinux - this is not an example of mustMatch as i am able to type anything i want.  In mustMatch, it resticts you to only type what is in the list.

Comment: @ooo I don't mean to be rude, but it is really  very bad experience to restrict typing. Consider this example: User uses other keyboard layout and wants to enter letter with accent but forgot to switch from EN layout. In such case he thinks that your page is broken. The best user experience is to allow enter anything and show that there are no results or invalid character typed.

Comment: @dziastinux - not rude at all. i disagree with your "restrict typing" opinion. This is how many autocompletes work across many apps (think default autocomplete behavior in winforms/wpf).  you are enforcing the idea that you only can choose from a distinct list.  If you allow other typing, then it seems like you support additional values.  The old plugin supported this behavior so regardless of anyone's opinion, i think its not right to remove functionality and not have a roadmap or a recommended solution for folks who are trying to upgrade.

Comment: @ooo - for apps - it is a different thing. Your forgot to mention that undesired symbol results in beep(alert) sound. Unfortunately currently there is no know way to play system sounds from the browser so this method is not suitable for web (at least yet). Take a look at facebook autocomplete, users easily understand that only suggested values are allowed to select.

Comment: @dziastinux - i see that you disagree with your restrict typing but that was the behavior of the old plugin so my users are demanding that this is replicated.  is there any solution in jquery ui autocomplete for mustmatch with multiple entries ??