# jQuery Autocomplete mustmatch doesn't have any effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.9. I have an autocomplete field that works really well, however I'd like to contrain the input to only what the autocomplete backend comes up with.

The documetation states:

> mustMatch Boolean Default: false
>
> If set to true, the autocompleter will
>   only allow results that are presented
>   by the backend.  Note that illegal
>   values result in an empty input box.

However, when I set mustMatch to true, it doesn't make any difference - I can still type in anything I like and nothing happens.

I'm fairly sure this is something I'm doing and not a bug as I haven't seen anything on google that points to that.

Here's a code snippet:

```
    $( ".client" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    mustMatch: true,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var term = request.term;
        if ( term in client_cache ) {
            response( client_cache[ term ] );
            return;
        }

        client_lastXhr = $.getJSON( "amex/start.php?action=autocomplete&field=client", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
            client_cache[ term ] = data;
            if ( xhr === client_lastXhr ) {
                response( data );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably found this option on the [documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) for the deprecated plugin. jQueryUI's current documentation is located [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

It looks like they removed the `mustMatch` option, but according to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587378/497356), you can implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For those in need of complete and **much simpler** solution, try this...

```
$("#my_autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: "my_data.php",
    change: function(e, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    },
    response: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length == 0) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }
}).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/dfc83/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear, only to return a value judgment json data inside a wood there, you can then empty it.

如果想要清空，只需要判断返回的json里面的某值有木有数据，然后清空就可以啦。

```
function selectRegion(){
$("#saleRegionSelect").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var cityId=$("[name='city']").val();
        var oppType=$("[name='primaryBiz']:checked").val();
        var site= $.trim($("#channel").val());
        if(oppType==undefined){
            return false;
        }
        if(site==undefined){
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: rootPath + "ajax/regionByCityAndSite",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                region: request.term,
                city:cityId,
                site:site,
                oppType:oppType
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.rows) { //Look at this line

                    $('#saleRegionSelect').val('');//clear
                    $('#saleRegion').val(''); //clear

                    response(($.map([], function (item) {
                        return {}
                    })));
                } else {
                    response(($.map(data.rows, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.region + ($.trim(item.saleName)==""?"":' (' + item.saleName + ')'),
                            value: item.region + ($.trim(item.saleName)==""?"":' (' + item.saleName + ')'),
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })));
                }
            }
        })
    },
    minLength: 1, 
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#saleRegion").val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

}

=> json :

```
{
"status": 200,
"message": "查询数据成功！",
"rows": [{
    "id": "678140138089353216",
    "oppType": 10,
    "saleId": "201402201431456839e855",
    "saleName": "陈",
    "creator": "zhangdanling",
    "createTime": "2015-12-19 17:26:29",
    "modifier": "zhangdanling",
    "modifyTime": "2015-12-22 11:11:35",
    "cityId": 147,
    "site": 1,
    "region": "测试测试",
    "remark": ""
}, {
    "id": "678847511099609088",
    "oppType": 10,
    "saleId": "201402201431456839e855",
    "saleName": "陈",
    "creator": "zhangdanling",
    "createTime": "2015-12-21 16:17:23",
    "modifier": "zhangdanling",
    "modifyTime": "2015-12-22 15:55:59",
    "cityId": 147,
    "site": 1,
    "region": "测试一区",
    "remark": ""
}, {
    "id": "678910954649423872",
    "oppType": 10,
    "saleId": "201402201431456839e855",
    "saleName": "陈",
    "creator": "zhangdanling",
    "createTime": "2015-12-21 20:29:30",
    "modifier": "zhangdanling",
    "modifyTime": "2015-12-21 20:29:30",
    "cityId": 147,
    "site": 1,
    "region": "测试区域三",
    "remark": ""
}, {
    "id": "679596181579374592",
    "oppType": 10,
    "saleId": "201407081036237ccfe9dc",
    "saleName": "张",
    "creator": "zhangdanling",
    "createTime": "2015-12-23 17:49:05",
    "modifier": "zhangdanling",
    "modifyTime": "2015-12-23 17:49:14",
    "cityId": 147,
    "site": 1,
    "region": "测试一下",
    "remark": ""
}, {
    "id": "680322348053700608",
    "oppType": 10,
    "saleId": "201407081036237ccfe9dc",
    "saleName": "张",
    "creator": "SYS_INIT",
    "createTime": "2015-12-25 17:54:20",
    "modifier": "SYS_INIT",
    "modifyTime": "2015-12-25 17:54:20",
    "cityId": 147,
    "site": 1,
    "region": "测试一下001",
    "remark": ""
}, {
    "id": "681308156487278592",
    "oppType": 10,
    "saleId": "201402201431456839e855",
    "saleName": "陈",
    "creator": "zhangdanling",
    "createTime": "2015-12-28 11:11:56",
    "modifier": "zhangdanling",
    "modifyTime": "2015-12-28 11:11:56",
    "cityId": 147,
    "site": 1,
    "region": "测试离职销售区域",
    "remark": ""
}]
```

}