# How to make an ASP.NET Page Fail Validation if a jQuery autocomplete() Field doesn't Match?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, autocomplete

After incorporating what I’ve learned by reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587378/how-to-implement-mustmatch-and-selectfirst-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete), I've figured out how to generate an error message when, in an [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) field the user enters text that doesn’t correspond to any of the available selections.

This page is an ASP.NET page which already has an infrastructure of ASP.NET validators on it. What I want to happen is to introduce a validator onto the page that causes page validation to fail when the user enters something not in the list. Here's what I have so far:

I started with Anonymous’s answer to the question above:

```
change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
             $(this).val('');
         }
    }
```

I replaced it with this in my `autocomplete()` javascript:

```
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
             $(""#" + lblAutocompleteError.ClientID + @""").show();
             $(""#" + txtDummy.ClientID + @""").val('');
        } else {
             $(""#" + lblAutocompleteError.ClientID + @""").hide();
             $(""#" + txtDummy.ClientID + @""").val('Dummy');
        }
    },
```

It’s javascript that’s being generated in code-behind rather than on the front end, that’s why it has all that literal string goodness...

And on the front end, I’ve declared two controls: `txtDummy` which I set and clear based on whether the autocomplete contains a matching string, and `rfvDummy` that requires said `TextBox` to be populated.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvDummy" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDummy" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDummy" Text="Dummy" Visible="false" />
```

Problem is, the `RequiredFieldValidator` isn’t failing when it should. More importantly, I get this sinking feeling that I’m going down the wrong path here. Creating a hidden `TextBox` and a `RequiredFieldValidator` seems like way too much of a hack for what I’m trying to accomplish. Is there a straightforward way to cause a page to fail validation, on the client side, with a message formatted like my other validators, when the user enters a value that is not in the autocomplete list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My autocomplete logic was correct, it was the means of hiding the `txtDummy` control that was not. By using

```
Visible="false"
```

the HTML for `txtDummy` is not generated, so the `RequiredFieldValidator` has nothing to look at. Changing the code for the `TextBox` to:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDummy" Text="Dummy" style="display: none;" />
```

allowed the HTML to be generated. When my `change` clause, above, is invoked, the page now fails validation when a matching item is not selected in the `TextBox`.